# How do I continuously run a single test case using Selenium?

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, testing, selenium

I have recorded a very simple test case Using the Selenium IDE integrated with Firefox.  I want the test case to run continuously over a period of time.  How can I make the test run continuously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) to launch the running of your tests from the command line.

1. Save your test from the IDE in a Test Suite
2. Run your test suite from the command-line [with the following syntax](http://seleniumhq.org/documentation/remote-control/languages/selenese.html).
3. Use your favorite scripting language to script the re-running of your test over and over

An alternate approach would be to save your test from the IDE into a Test Suite, and then open the suite in a text editor and copy/paste the same tests hundreds/thousands of times.  I've never tried it, but assuming the IDE doesn't choke on large Suite files, this would let you run the test X number of times again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [flowControl](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/flowControl) Selenium extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your test to run continuously in Selenium IDE then use infinite while loop command provided in IDE extension plug-in like [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks) IDE extension Plug in.

steps look like:

```
<tr>
<td>while</td>
<td>true</td>
<td></td>
```

Your steps

```
<tr>
<td>endWhile</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

You can also utilize define module command provided in ISFW plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
Command   Target    Value
Label     Jump1
Your Script Line1
Line2
Line3
goto      Jump1
```

This will keep on executing the set of your commands again and again.

Comment: This assumes that you have the Selblocks extension installed: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/